# File Download dialogue is not displayed when we download a file

Tags: asp.net

Click to download Excel File

I am using the above hyper link in my application to allow the users to download an Excel file.When I click on the hyperlink button it is displaying a file download dialogue box, but when I do the same thing in the server it is opening the Excel file as a web page.

What would be the reason for this issue?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your browser in one of the boxes knows how to handle an Excel spreadsheet, probably because you installed Excel and the other box doesn't know how to handle Excel.  This is all controlled by the `Content` headers.  Right now you are sending only the MIME type in the `Content-Type` header.  What you need to do is also send the `Content-Disposition`.

You need to set the Content-Disposition on the header.

```
Content-Disposition = attachment; filename=filename.xls
```

Or, **if you cannot modify the application**, which it doesn't sound like is the case, you can modify the MIME type to

```
Content-Type = application/download
```

You can find an example of this in this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279667).

Comment: Hi,
   Where do we need to add 
   Content-Type = application/download
   Content-Disposition = attachment; filename=test.txt
Do we need to add it in the page header ?

Comment: You will need to link to an intermediary web page that will allow you to change the headers. Create an empty ASPX page with only a Page_Load event that sets the headers (Response.AppendHeader) and then just dumps out the contents of the file, possibly using Response.TransmitFile.